# Using twidlr in combination with purrr

Tags: r, purrr

```
library(purrr)
library(tidyverse)
library(twidlr)

# this works
mtcars %>% lm(mpg ~ wt)

# this does not work
mtcars %>% split(.$cyl)  %>% map(~ lm(mpg ~ wt))

# this does work
mtcars %>% split(.$cyl)  %>% map(~ lm(., mpg ~ wt))
```

The promise of twidlr is that it can work with piping, but it seems that it only works consistently with the "." convention, or am I missing something?

Comment: Quick solution to include `split`: `mtcars %>% split(.$cyl)  %>% map(lm, mpg ~ wt)`

Answer (score 1):

A `%>%` inserts the previous object as the first argument to a function. But the `%>%` in your expression:

```
mtcars %>% split(.$cyl)  %>% map(~ lm(mpg ~ wt))
```

Applies to the object `mtcars %>% split(.$cyl)` being inserted to the function `map()`, not to the function `lm()`. Thus the pipe is still working, and twidlr is still replacing the functionality of `lm`, but the expression has no way of knowing you'd want to provide a first argument to lm.

This would be true of any `map` expression. For example:

```
1:4 %>% map(~ mean())
```

wouldn't know to insert an argument into the `mean()` function.

Comment: Just adding, this also relates to use of `~`, which is a shortcut for creating an anonymous function. Check out "The map functions" in "R for Data Science" for details: http://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html#the-map-functions